# Converting JSON to model object Android

Tags: android, json

I'm new to using JSON in Android and have been running into a few problems creating a model object from the JSON. If anyone knows of any good tutorials or resources that would be good to look into for more details I'd really appreciate them. I've been looking at the tutorial on Vogella and in the Bignerdranch Android book thus far.

I'm able to pull in the JSON and create a JSONobject, however my surveys aren't saving.

Here's the JSON I'm trying to parse:

```
    [
        {
            "title": "Pepsi or Coke?",
            "id": 1,
            "questions": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "title": "Which pop do you prefer?",
                    "single_response": true,
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "title": "Pepsi",
                            "id": 1
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Coke",
                            "id": 2
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Mountain Dew",
                            "id": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "title": "What's your age?",
                    "single_response": true,
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "title": "18-24",
                            "id": 4
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "25-34",
                            "id": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "35-50",
                            "id": 6
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "50+",
                            "id": 7
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "title": "What's your political association?",
                    "single_response": true,
                    "answers": [
                        {
                            "title": "Republican",
                            "id": 8
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Democrat",
                            "id": 9
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I'm retrieving the json like this:

```
byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return null;
                }

                int bytesRead = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                out.close();
                return out.toByteArray();
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        public String getUrl(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
            return new String(getUrlBytes(urlSpec));
        }
```

And here's where I parse it:

```
public ArrayList<Survey> getSurveys(String apiKey) throws JSONException {
    ArrayList<Survey> surveys = new ArrayList<Survey>();

    try {
        String url = Uri.parse(ENDPOINT).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("auth_token", apiKey).build().toString();
        String jsonString = getUrl(url);
        Log.i(TAG, "Received json string: " + jsonString);

        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i ++) {
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i(TAG, "Object is: " + object.toString());
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                Survey survey = new Survey(array.getJSONObject(i));
                surveys.add(survey);
                Log.i(TAG, "Survey is: " + survey.toString());
            }  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Survey didn't save");
        }

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to retrieve surveys: " + ioe);
    }
    return surveys; 
}
```

I'm assuming that the issue is in my create survey method itself since the JSONobjects are created correctly, but the surveys aren't saving. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
public Survey(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        mId = UUID.fromString(json.getString("id"));
        if (json.has("title")) {
            mTitle = json.getString("title");
        }
}
```

As always any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I was trying to convert the int id that was getting sent in JSON to a UUID.

As long as the data types match up the items are created correctly.